# Divs to sit side by side as a square

Tags: html, css

I have managed to arrange my elements in a row in desktop mode which is great, but for mobile mode, I want to show the 4 images as a 'square', unfortunately, I can't seem to get the CSS right, I think somewhere along the way I have got something wrong...

I've been trying to get them not just to show in a square (which i can manage to do using float, only for when the width is below a certain level (480) but then i can't centralise the divs, nor have their margins at a decent level, I've missed something at one of the container divs and it's driven be a bit insane, hence the reach for help.

This is what I'm trying to achieve(desktop):

[image]

And here is the goal for mobile:

[image]

WHAT I ACTUALLY HAVE:

DESKTOP (WHICH LOOKS CORRECT): 
[image]

MOBILE MODE (WHICH IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS - I NEED IT TO LOOK LIKE THE SQUARED IMAGE ABOVE:

[image]

What happens when I try to float the images is they sit to the left of the page and don't have appropriate margins.

Here is the html and css:

```
<div class="shopifySectionInstagram">



 <div style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px 0;"class="instagramContainer">
    <div style="margin: 10px 0;" class="instaSection">
      <div style="margin-left: calc(20px / 2); margin-right: calc(20px / 2); box-sizing: border-box; position: relative; width: calc(75% - 20px);" class="instaContentContainer">
       <span style="text-align: center; font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #454545;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                    text-decoration: underline;"class="instaText" >

         <a href="https://www.instagram.com/123/" target="_blank">
                     Visit our instagram

         </a>
        </span>

        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;" class="instaImagesContainer">        
          <div class="instaImage">
                     <a href="https://www.instagram.com/123/" target="_blank">
         <img class="instaImageSource" src="{{ 'instaPic1.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Logo">
         </a>

          </div>          
          <div class="instaImage">
                     <a href="https://www.instagram.com/seacasterofficial/" target="_blank">
<img class="instaImageSource" src="{{ 'instaPic2.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Logo">
         </a>

          </div>                    
          <div class="instaImage">
                     <a href="https://www.instagram.com/123/" target="_blank">
<img class="instaImageSource" src="{{ 'instaPic7.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Logo">
         </a>

          </div>                   
          <div class="instaImage">
                     <a href="https://www.instagram.com/123/" target="_blank">
<img class="instaImageSource" src="{{ 'instaPic5.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Logo">
         </a>

          </div>

        </div>
    </div>  
   </div>
  </div>
</div>


CSS (it's all inline css EXCEPT for the following: 

    .instaImageSource {
      height: 140px;
      width: 140px !important;
      max-width: none !important;
    }



    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .instaContentContainer {
        width: 100% !important; 
     }
    }


    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .instaImagesContainer {
        display: block !important; 
     }
    }
```

SORRY FOR THE LONG POST I WANTED TO BE AS DESCRIPTIVE AS POSSIBLE.

THANK YOU SO MUCH IF YOU CAN HELP. I KNOW SOMEWHERE I'VE BUGGERED SOMETHING UP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your styles are doing a lot of extraneous work and it's making things harder. Here's a simpler approach using CSS-Grid:

```css
img { 
  max-width: 100%;
}

.shopifySectionInstagram {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #454545;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.instaImagesContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(auto, 140px));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .instaImagesContainer {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shopifySectionInstagram">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/seacasterofficial/" target="_blank">
    Visit our instagram
  </a>

  <div class="instaImagesContainer">
    <div class="instaImage">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/seacasterofficial/" target="_blank">
        <img src="//placehold.it/140">
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="instaImage">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/seacasterofficial/" target="_blank">
        <img src="//placehold.it/140">
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="instaImage">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/seacasterofficial/" target="_blank">
        <img src="//placehold.it/140">
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="instaImage">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/seacasterofficial/" target="_blank">
        <img src="//placehold.it/140">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Corey, I've not heard of / used a CSS grid before, I'll try it out now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`block` elements expand to fill the available space. I recommend you change the entire structure of this as @coreyward said given that it is quite rudimentary but if you want a simple fix, change `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

One more way using flex will be:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .instaContentContainer {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
     }

    .instaImage {
       width: 50%;
       text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Float is outdated in todays CSS now when you got [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).

Flex is a little bit stupid when it comes to margins, and if you want spacing, it's easier to put the elements in a container with a padding and use `box-sizing` to make the item's padding to be included into the size.

The code below automatically wraps items with screen width.

```css
:root {
  --spacing: 1rem;
  --spacing-half: calc(var(--spacing) / 2);
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item,
.image-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: var(--spacing-half);
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing);
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  background-size: cover;
  
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(50%);
}

.image-container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--spacing);
  bottom: var(--spacing);
  left: var(--spacing);
  right: var(--spacing);
  border: 1px solid #121212;
}

.first.image-container {
  background: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/11/200/200.jpg");
}

.second.image-container {
  background: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/23/200/200.jpg");
}

.third.image-container {
  background: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/35/200/200.jpg");
}

.fourth.image-container {
  background: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/47/200/200.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="first image-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="second image-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="third image-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="fourth image-container"></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```